# What is the proper way to enable cub in cupy?

Tags: python-3.x, cupy, cub

I am trying to figure out the proper way to enable `cub` in `cupy`, but without success so far. I looked into the documentation and I couldn't find anything. At the moment I enable `cub` like this:

```
import cupy.core._accelerator as _acc
_acc.set_routine_accelerators(['cub'])
_acc.set_reduction_accelerators(['cub'])
```

Before executing the above code, `cub` is disabled. I confirm that by running:

```
cupy.core.get_reduction_accelerators()
cupy.core.get_routine_accelerators()
```

which return an empty list (`[]`). After running the code in the first snippet the above functions return `[1]` (whatever that means). Also, I can notice a massive performance difference in functions like `cupy.nansum`.

As you can see though, the functions `cupy.set_routine_accelerators` and `cupy.set_reduction_accelerators` belong to a private API (`cupy.core._accelerator`) which implies that I shouldn't call them.

- What is the proper way to enable `cub` in `cupy`?

I am using `Python 3.7.6` and `cupy 8.1.0`

Thank you

Comment: The documented way of doing it is through the `CUPY_ACCELERATORS` env var.
`export CUPY_ACCELERATORS=cub`.
https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/environment.html

As you noticed, `set_*_accelerators` is mostly a private API that we use for testing.
The reason for them returning 1 is that we use an Enum, I agree it is confusing ... maybe we can change it :).

Comment: Oh I missed that part of the documentation! Silly me! Thanks a lot for the quick answer my friend! Feel free to add this comment as a response and I will be happy to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documented way of doing it is through the CUPY_ACCELERATORS env var. export CUPY_ACCELERATORS=cub. docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/environment.html As you noticed, set_*_accelerators is mostly a private API that we use for testing. The reason for them returning 1 is that we use an Enum, I agree it is confusing ... maybe we can change it :).